Why does my interface using ReturnType have 'any' as a type?
I have an interface using TypeScript's ReturnType to properly set the type of a value that is determined from the returned type of a function. The function has a specific return type.
Strangely, the type (when I hover over it in VS Code) is any - see SomeInterface.hasAnyType in the example code below.
I can't seem to reproduce this though with my own function, eg SomeInterface.hasAType in the code below. It only happens when I use createSolanaRpcFromTransport() (to reiterate, that function does have a return type). I suspect it may be related to createSolanaRpcFromTransport() using generics. But I'd really like to avoid the type being any here and fix the problem.
Why does my interface using ReturnType have 'any' as a type?
import { createSolanaRpcFromTransport } from "@solana/web3.js";

const sayHello = () => {
  return "Hello";
};

interface SomeInterface {
  // This uses ReturnType, and has 'string' for a type. Great!
  hasAType: ReturnType<typeof sayHello>;
  // This also uses ReturnType, but has 'any' for a type. Why?
  hasAnyType: ReturnType<typeof createSolanaRpcFromTransport>;
}

Screenshot of VS Code showing SomeInterface.hasAnyType has any as a type:

Update: some further testing show the any goes away if I don't use ReturnType and paste the return type of createSolanaRpcFromTransport():
import {
  RpcFromTransport,
  SolanaRpcApiFromTransport,
  RpcTransport,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

... 

interface SomeInterface {
  ...
  // Now this actually has a type!
  hasAnyType: RpcFromTransport<SolanaRpcApiFromTransport<RpcTransport>, RpcTransport>; // ReturnType<typeof createSolanaRpcFromTransport>;
}

However it would nice to use ReturnType and not have to repeat the type information for  createSolanaRpcFromTransport().
Update: As requested, info from createSolanaRpcFromTransport hover:
(alias) function createSolanaRpcFromTransport<TTransport extends RpcTransport>(transport: TTransport): RpcFromTransport<SolanaRpcApiFromTransport<TTransport>, TTransport>
import createSolanaRpcFromTransport
Creates a new Solana RPC using a custom transport.

or as a screenshot: 

could you share the vscode result of the createSolanaRpcFromTransport function? (I mean hover on it and share screenshot)

@YasinTazeoglu done, see above.

Might need to see more detail but I'm guess the answer will be found within the definition for RpcFromTransport. Note that in your working version there is nothing generic (no TTransport). Do you still have the same any type if you use ReturnType<typeof createSolanaRpcFromTransport<RpcTransport>>?

Do you think this depends on solana-web3js expertise? Then please tag the question as such. If not, you should really try to disentangle the question from it so that it's self contained.  Otherwise the only reasonable way forward for someone to test an answer they give is to try to install solana-web3js somewhere and inspect its types, so it's not really a [mre] (unless.. maybe you can give us a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates it?). How should we proceed here?

@jcalz no, it doesn't require solana-web3.js expertise. I did try to disentangle it, and produce a minimal reproducible example (that's why this is only 10 lines) and tried to do it using no dependencies but couldn't replicate the behavior when I used another function - hence the hasAType example in the code above.

So then what can we do? I mean, maybe someone can help you without reproducing it, but I'm at a loss. Presumably the answer lies in the types of solana-web3, and you could try to produce a standalone version of those types; but barring that, all I can do is shrug. A link to a web IDE project might be more fruitful? I don't know. I'll disengage now so as not to clutter up the comments more. If I see an [edit] here that gives something more concrete to go on, I'll check back in. Good luck, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

@jcalz "So then what can we do?" install the library, then use the 10-line minimal reproducible example provided in the question.
